# Qt Quick layout changes on different events

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

When I execute my QML code, the output is:

[image]

When I minimize the window, It becomes like

[image]

and finally, when I again maximize the window it changes to

[image]

the GUI which I want to make looks like

![][5]

I am not getting what is the issue for all of the changes in GUI at different events. And this is the Qml code which I wrote

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 1080
    height: 720
    title: qsTr("Login")
    GridLayout{

          Rectangle{
                    id:one
              Rectangle
              { id:two
                  color:"black";

                  width: 700
                  height:40
              }

              Image {
                  id: image
                  x: 470
                  y: 0
                  width: 54
                  height: 42
                  source: "qrc:/user.png"

              }
              Rectangle
                  {
                      id:three;
                       color:"#f47a42";
                       width: 200
                       height:40
                      anchors.left:two.right;
                     anchors.margins:940
                 Text {

                  id: user
                  text: qsTr("4200")
                  color:"white"
                  anchors.top: value.bottom
              }
              Text
              {
                  id: value;
                  text: qsTr("User");
                  color:"yellow"
              }}
          }
    }

    Rectangle{
        ColumnLayout{
            width: 50
            height: childrenRect.height+fillHeight;

        }
        color:"green"
    }


}
```

So why this is happening and how can I solve this problem?
[Output of the code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pghr8.png)

Comment: Your `GridLayout` has no size. Perhaps you want to set is `anchors.fill: parent`

Comment: I tried but it isn't working.

Comment: Your code is full of inconsistencies and oddities. What is `fillHeight` in this line `childrenRect.height+fillHeight`. The titlebar should be organized in some row layout, not with fixed sizes. For what you set giant margins in `three`? You should work on the layout issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example of scalable window:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600
    title: qsTr("Layout example")
    ColumnLayout{
        spacing: 0
        anchors.fill: parent
        Item {
            id: titlebar
            Layout.preferredHeight: 40
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            RowLayout {
                anchors.fill: parent
                spacing: 0
                Rectangle {
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    color: "orange"
                    Text {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text: "Title"
                    }
                }
                Rectangle {
                    Layout.preferredWidth: 100
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    color: "lightgreen"
                    Text {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text: "Actions"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id:  content
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            color: "lightyellow"
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "Content"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The layout is right. But the problem isn't solved yet when I minimize the window, the problem again happens.

Comment: Did you try my example? I see no problem. I can minimize or maximize the window and the layout remains as is.

Comment: I am adding the screenshot in my question.

Comment: Is it any other thing which I have to set.